# DataFrame.show() throwing error in Databricks

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-synapse

I am trying to get data from Azure Data Warehouse using Azure Databricks.

Connection part is good as I can see the rows returned in DataFrame but when I try to save or show the record in DataFrame it throws error. Here is what I have tried:

```
df = spark.read \
  .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw") \
  .option("url", sqlDwNew) \
  .option("tempDir", temDir_location) \
  .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true") \
  .option("query", "select  * from AccessPermission") \
  .load()
df.count()
```

### Output

```
(1) Spark Jobs
df:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
AccessPermissionId:integer
AccessPermission:string
Out[16]: 4
```

### Error

```
df.show()
```

### Output

```
com.databricks.spark.sqldw.SqlDWSideException: SQL DW failed to execute the JDBC query produced by the connector.
```

Comment: If my answer useful for you, could you please [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? It may help more people who have similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know exact reason, I would request you to check out the complete stack trace and try to find root cause of the issue.

As per my repro, I have faced exactly same error message and able to resolve the issue by looking at the stack trace and found issue with the configuration of the storage account.

```
com.databricks.spark.sqldw.SqlDWSideException: SQL DW failed to execute the JDBC query produced by the connector.
.
.
.
.
.   

 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: No access key found in the session conf or the global Hadoop conf for Azure Storage account name: chepra
```

[image]

**Step1:** Set up the Blob storage account access key in the notebook session configuration.

```
spark.conf.set(
  "fs.azure.account.key.<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net",
  "<your-storage-account-access-key>")
```

**Step2:** Load data from an Azure Synapse query.

```
df = spark.read \
  .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw") \
  .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://<the-rest-of-the-connection-string>") \
  .option("tempDir", "wasbs://<your-container-name>@<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<your-directory-name>") \
  .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true") \
  .option("query", "select  * from table") \
  .load()
```

**Step3:** Display or Show dataframe

```
df.show()
display(df)
```

[image]

[image]

**Reference:** [Azure Databricks - Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/synapse-analytics)

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: thanks for the hint, I checked the full stack trace and the issue was related to DWH login user rights.